# How to make changes to Core Data objects from different threads without having to save after every change

Tags: iphone, multithreading, core-data

I have perused all related threads on SO but still confused about how to make changes to core data objects from multiple threads without having to save after every change.

I am working on an app that talks to the server constantly. The app uses Core Data for storage and `NSFetchedResultsController` is used in a few view controllers to fetch data from the persistence store. Usually when the user performs an action, a network request will be triggered. Before the network request is sent, usually some changes should be made to relevant Core Data objects, and upon server response, more changes would be made to those Core Data objects.

Initially all the Core Data operations were done on the main thread in the same `NSManagedObjectContext`. It was all well except that when network traffic is high, the app can become unresponsive for several seconds. Obviously that's not acceptable so I looked into moving some Core Data operations to run in the background.

The first approach I tried was to create an NSOperation object to process each network response. Inside the main method of the NSOperation object, I set up a dedicated MOC, make some changes, and commit the changes at the end.

```
- (void)main
{
    @try {
        NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

        // Create a dedicated MOC for this NSOperation
        NSManagedObjectContext * context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
        [context setPersistentStoreCoordinator:[APP_DELEGATE persistentStoreCoordinator]];

        // Make change to Core Data objects
        // ...

        // Commit the changes
        NSError *error = nil;
        if ([context hasChanges] && ![context save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }

        // Release the MOC
        [context release];

        // Drain the pool
        [pool drain];
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        // Important that we don't rethrow exception here
        NSLog(@"Exception: %@", exception);
    }
}
```

The MOC on the main thread is registered for the `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification`.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(backgroundContextDidSave:)
                                             name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

So when the background context commits changes, the main MOC will be notified and then will merge in the changes:

```
- (void)backgroundContextDidSave:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    // Make sure we're on the main thread when updating the main context
    if (![NSThread isMainThread]) {
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(backgroundContextDidSave:) withObject:notification waitUntilDone:NO];
        return;
    }

    // Merge the changes into the main context
    [[self managedObjectContext] mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification];
}
```

However, as I mentioned earlier, I also need to make changes to Core Data objects from the main MOC. Each change is usually very small (e.g. update one instance variable in an object) but there can be many of them. So I really don't want to save the main MOC after every single change. But if I don't do that, I run into problems when merging changes from background MOC to the main MOC. Merge conflicts occur since both MOCs have unsaved changes. Setting the merge policy doesn't help either, since I want to keep changes from both MOCs.

One possibility is to register the background MOC with the `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` as well, but that approach smells like bad design for me. And I would still need to save the main MOC after every single change.

The second approach I tried was to do all Core Data changes from a dedicated background context running on a permanent background thread.

```
- (NSThread *)backgroundThread
{
    if (backgroundThread_ == nil) {
        backgroundThread_ = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(backgroundThreadMain) object:nil];
        // Actually start the thread
        [backgroundThread_ start];
    }
    return backgroundThread_;
}

// Entry point of the background thread
- (void)backgroundThreadMain
{
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    // We can't run the runloop unless it has an associated input source or a timer, so we'll just create a timer that will never fire.
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:DBL_MAX target:self selector:@selector(ignore) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run];

    // Create a dedicated NSManagedObjectContext for this thread.
    backgroundContext_ = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
    [backgroundContext_ setPersistentStoreCoordinator:[self persistentStoreCoordinator]];

    [pool drain];
}
```

So whenever I need to make Core Data changes from the main thread, I have to get the objectID from the main thread, and pass to the background thread to perform the change. When the background context saves, the changes will then be merged back to the main MOC.

```
- (void)addProduct:(Product *)product toCatalog:(Catalog *)catalog;
```

would change to:

```
- (void)addProduct:(NSManagedObjectID *)productObjectId toCatalog:(NSManagedObjectID *)catalogObjectId
{
    NSArray * params = [NSArray dictionaryWithObjects:productObjectId, catalogObjectId, nil];
    [self performSelector:(addProductToCatalogInBackground:) onThread:backgroundThread_ withObject:params waitUntilDone:NO];
}
```

But this seems so convoluted and ugly. Writing code like this seems to negate the usefulness of using Core Data in the first place. Also, I would still have to save the MOC after every single change since I can't get objectId for a new object without saving it to the datastore first.

I feel that I am missing something here. I really hope someone can shed some light on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `NSManagedObjectContext` is just a scratch pad.  The act of saving it moves the changes in one scratch pad down to the `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` and potentially down to disk. The only way one MOC can know about the changes from another MOC is through the `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`.  Therefore the save is required.  However, saving is a LOT less expensive in the next release of iOS.

If you must be iOS4 or less compliant then saving is the only option.  However you can load up the saves and do them less frequently depending on the design of your application.  If you are importing data then save when the import is complete or in logical units inside of the import.  There is no need to save after every entry, that is wasteful.

BTW, I would suggest using `NSOperation` instances instead of working with `NSThread` instances directly.  They are easier to work with and will perform better.

Also, you do not need to wrap Objective-C code in try/catch blocks.  Very few things will throw an exception; especially on iOS.

Lastly, I would suggest taking a look at [my post on CIMGF](http://www.cimgf.com/2011/08/22/importing-and-displaying-large-data-sets-in-core-data/) about importing on a background thread.

Comment: Hi Marcus, I went through your post and did similar approach in my app but sometimes my UI is unresponsive for few seconds when it try to merge the changes and I am not sure how to avoid that since merge changes are happening on Mainthread

Comment: The merge to the main thread will cause the main thread to block during the merge.  The way to avoid this (pre-iOS 5) is to save in smaller chunks so that the main thread has time to do other things.  You want to keep the saves short so that they are not human perceivable.

Comment: Yup... currently my save operation works in chunk of 15 records for more than 1000 records and i observed that UI unresponsiveness is improved but still there for split of seconds i think i will try it with less records per chunk to check if it improves..

Comment: too short and your frequency goes up and you have the same issue all over again.  It is a tough thing to deal with which is why it was resolved in iOS4.  Another option you might consider is to not do a merge at all.  Just reset the master context once the save is complete and force it to refresh itself.  Doesn't work in every app but something to consider.

Comment: Thanks for your tips..I am able to make it work without any issues by keeping 15 records per merge. but still in testing phase as I need to verify it across multiple OS versions..Also resetting will not work in my case as user accessing data from DB throughout the app and it may create UI unresponsiveness while resetting context..